# How to find out disk space/storage usage from photo storage in a SharePoint profile

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync, sync

Does anyone know how to query the amount of space that is being used by storing photos in the my sites section of SharePoint?  There has been concern that syncing photos to Active Directory will bloat AD but I have no way to know if it is 10MB or 10GB of data.

Alternatively, is there a way perhaps to configure Active Directory to just pull the photo from SharePoint instead of storing and replicating it within its own database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this by going to http://yourservername/my/user%photos/

This takes you to a picture library that houses all uploaded photos.  It will contain three images per person (three different sizes).

Once you get to this location you can open the folder in explorer view, select properties and see what the size is as well as how many files are present.

Answer (score 2):

The file size in AD is capped to something like 10k. It does not sync the large files.